# Change ServiceOverride after component registration in Castle

Tags: castle-windsor

I have two components registered for a service:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IDataStorage>().Named("FirstChoice").ImplementedBy...
    Component.For<IDataStorage>().Named("SecondChoice").ImplementedBy
```

Then I have a set of components deriving from this base class, that depends on those components:

```
public abstract class BaseMessageHandler
{
    public IDataStorage FirstStorage {get; set;}

    public IDataStorage SecondStorage {get; set;}
}
```

If I was registering these "handlers" (deriving from BaseMessageHandler) manually, I would specify a service override, indicating which component I want for properties "FirstStorage" and "SecondStorage". Something like:

```
.Configure(x => x.DependsOn(
    ServiceOverride.ForKey("FirstStorage").Eq("FirstChoice"),
    ServiceOverride.ForKey("SecondStorage").Eq("SecondChoice"))
```

Unfortunately, this registration is done automatically by a framework (NServiceBus). I know that if I register the handlers first (before NServiceBus has a chance to do so), these registrations will stick. But rather than try to guess and mimick the registration NServiceBus does, I wonder if I can specify service overrides in a custom IContributeComponentModelConstruction.
It seems a good place to do so, and I'm able to find these properties:

```
public class DataStorageOverrideContributor : IContributeComponentModelConstruction
{
    public void ProcessModel(Castle.MicroKernel.IKernel kernel, Castle.Core.ComponentModel model)
    {
        var dataStorageDependencies = model.Properties.Where(
            x => x.Dependency.TargetItemType == typeof(IDataStorage));

        foreach (var propertyDependency in dataStorageDependencies)
        {
            // now what??
```

but I'm not sure the proper way to:

- check if a service override is already specified (in which case I would do nothing)
- add a service override to a property dependency.

Is this something that could be done inspecting and working the ComponentModel in the IContributeComponentModelConstruction.ProcessModel method?

Comment: Could you call remove and re-register?

     if (_container.Kernel.HasComponent(name))
         _container.Kernel.RemoveComponent(name);
     _container.Register(Component.For<T>().ImplementedBy(component).Named(name).LifeStyle.Singleton);

Comment: In this case, I can register the component before NServiceBus does it, getting the same results. But it feels a little wrong having to do all that if I just want to change a dependency override.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a subdependency resolver in your scenario. You can see the code below on how to use it.

Goodluck,

Marwijn.

public interface IDataStorage
    {
    }

```
public class DataStore1 : IDataStorage
{
}

public class DataStore2 : IDataStorage
{
}

public class BaseMessageHandler
{
    public IDataStorage FirstStorage { get; set; }
    public IDataStorage SecondStorage { get; set; }
}

public class SubDependencyResolver : ISubDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public SubDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public bool CanResolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model,
                           DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        return model.Implementation == typeof (BaseMessageHandler) && dependency.TargetType == typeof(IDataStorage);
    }

    public object Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model,
                          DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        var handlers = _kernel.GetHandlers(dependency.TargetType);
        switch (dependency.DependencyKey)
        {
            case "FirstStorage":
                return handlers.Single(h => h.ComponentModel.Implementation == typeof (DataStore1)).Resolve(context);
            case "SecondStorage":
                return handlers.Single(h => h.ComponentModel.Implementation == typeof(DataStore2)).Resolve(context);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new SubDependencyResolver(container.Kernel));
        container.Register(
            Component.For<IDataStorage>().Named("FirstChoice").ImplementedBy<DataStore1>(),
            Component.For<IDataStorage>().Named("SecondChoice").ImplementedBy<DataStore2>(),
            Component.For<BaseMessageHandler>()
            );

        var messageHandler = container.Resolve<BaseMessageHandler>();
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(DataStore1), messageHandler.FirstStorage.GetType());
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(DataStore2), messageHandler.SecondStorage.GetType());
    }
}
```

alternative you may use:

```
case "FirstStorage":
   return handlers.Single(h => h.ComponentModel.Name == "FirstChoice").Resolve(context);
case "SecondStorage":
   return handlers.Single(h => h.ComponentModel.Name == "SecondChoice").Resolve(context);
```

to resolve on component name rather then implementation type.

Comment: Thanks Marwijn. This seems to fit the bill and I will probably use it, but the concept seems not quite right, meaning that a ISubDependencyResolver looks like something that should be used for decisions that affect the dependency choice at run time, where the situation I described was more a matter of "registration time".
I was curious if this can actually be achieved in the IContributeComponentModelConstruction.